# Kafkatool.exe failed create new KafkaAdminClient SASL_PLAINTEXT

Tags: windows-10, kerberos

I have created a **kerberized** Kafka cluster. It is working fine and I can produce and consume messages. Now I want to use the [kafkatool2](http://www.kafkatool.com/) software, and I am running the program through cmd by this command:

```
kafkatool.exe -J-Djava.security.auth.login.config=d:\client_jaas.conf
```

But after filling up the blank spaces I am getting this **error**:

[ERROR Kafkatool.exe - SASL_PLAINTEXT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEWQH.png)

This is my **JAAS** file:

```
Server {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useKeyTab=true
  keyTab="D:\kafkaadmin.keytab"
  storeKey=true
  useTicketCache=false
  principal="admin/kafkatool@TEST.COM";
};

KafkaServer {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required debug=true
  useKeyTab=true
  storeKey=true
  keyTab="D:\kafkaadmin.keytab"
  principal="admin/kafkatool@TEST.COM";
};

// For Zookeeper Client
Client {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required debug=true
  useKeyTab=true
  storeKey=true
  keyTab="D:\kafkaadmin.keytab"
  principal="admin/kafkatool@TEST.COM";
};

KafkaClient {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required debug=true
  useKeyTab=true
  storeKey=true
  keyTab="D:\kafkaadmin.keytab"
  principal="admin/kafkatool@TEST.COM";
};
```

What should I have missing?

Kafka-cluster OS: Ubuntu 14.04
User OS: Windows 10 Enterprise

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue in my virtual machine when I tried to look at messages in the kerberized kafka environment. Try setting   serviceName="kafka" in your KafkaClient configuration.

Also make sure you run kafkatool by passing -J-Djava.security.auth.login.config as an argument.

Example client JAAS configuration:

```
KafkaClient {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  serviceName="kafka"
  useKeyTab=true
  keyTab="<path_to>/user.keytab"
  principal="user@domain";
};
```

I used the tool in linux environment but I think the above will solve the issue for windows as well.